# App crash with distriqt scanner ane on Android

Tags: actionscript, ane, distriqt

I use the distriqt scanner ane and it works very vell on iOS. But with the similar app on Android it crashes the app immediately (while calling Scanner.service.startScan( options ))

I got follwing from logcat:

```
E/QCOM PowerHAL(  313): Invalid hint ID.
E/mm-camera-intf(  313): mm_camera_open:  opened, break out while loop
E/InputDispatcher(  858): channel '2da9ab5b air.myfunnyappidcovered/air.myfunnyappidcovered.AppEntry (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
E/InputDispatcher(  858): channel 'e01d279 air.myfunnyappidcovered/com.distriqt.extension.scanner.zbar.ZBarScannerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Any Idea? All permissions and permission-freatures are set. The AS-Code works, like the iOS-compile shows. Tested with the same result on different Android-devices.

Comment: Update: I separated it from the mainapp and it runs well, also on android. But there is nothing special in the mainapp - no other ane or camera implementation.I've tried to hook it by compiling the ane and my own scanner-class in a single SWF and imports it on runtime. Sounds impossible, but works ... only on iOS again.

Comment: Is there an exception or something causing the app to exit in the logs?

Comment: Double check if you compile your main app and test app with the same compiler settings, SDK etc. Other than that i can recommend the qreader ANE - its very fast and work on both. The only problem is that you might need to get an older build of it if you will get some vmware errors (i believe) on iOS (i believe - don't remember exactly :))